# Dynamically change logs level in uvicorn

Tags: python, logging, uvicorn

I have a Fastapi API running with uvicorn. I use uvicorn logging like so:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host=host, port=int(port), reload=True, log_level=log_level,
                log_config="config/logging.yaml")
```

What I would like to achive is beeing able to change the log_level through an endpoint.
Something like:

```py
@app.put("/api/log/{level}")
def change_log_level(level):
    #something that changes the log level.
```

I tried to make a global variable `log_level` but it didn't work and I'm not sure how to change it as the log_level is in the `uvicorn.run` instruction. It is as well in the config.yaml file, so I'm not really sure were to change it...
I'm open to try the logging with another library if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
@app.put("/api/log/{level}")
def change_log_level(level):
    logging_level = your_function_to_map_url_level_to_logging_level(level)
    logging.getLogger('uvicorn').setLevel(logging_level)
```

You might want to do this for logger `'uvicorn'` as above, or perhaps `'uvicorn.access'` or `'uvicorn.error'`, or any combination of these.

There's a `uvicorn.config.LOG_LEVELS` dictionary mapping strings like `'critical'` to `logging.CRITICAL`, etc. You might want to use that in `your_function_to_map_url_level_to_logging_level`, but you'd need to handle invalid levels passed in via the URL.

Comment: du you know if there is somewher a documentation for `uvicorn.config.LOG_LEVELS` ? couldn't find any...

Comment: @Aude No, I used the source ...